# Unable to compute integral on implicit region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am new to Mathematica. I need to deal with the following computation

```
rr[t_] := ImplicitRegion[(x0^2 - y0^2) Exp[-t] + (x1^2 - y1^2) Exp[t - 1] -  x2^2 + y2^2 == 0 &&  x0 y0 Exp[-t] + x1 y1 Exp[t - 1] - x2 y2 == 0 &&  x0^2 + x1^2 + x2^2 + y0^2 + y1^2 + y2^2 == 1, {x0, y0, x1, y1, x2,  y2}]
```

(sorry for the length) and

```
g[t_] :=  Integrate[(((y0^2 - x0^2) Exp[-t] + (x1^2 - y1^2) Exp[ t - 1])^2 + (-2 x0 y0 Exp[-t] + 
    2 x1 y1 Exp[t - 1])^2)/(4 (x0^2 + y0^2) Exp[-2 t] + 
 4 (x1^2 + y1^2) Exp[2 t - 2] + 4 (x2^2 + y2^2)), {x0, y0, x1, y1,
 x2, y2} \[Element] rr[t], Assumptions -> 0 <= t <= 1]
```

Now this code takes forever to run. So I tried to do it numerically, by using `NIntegrate`, but I get the following message:

```
DiscretizeRegion: The region given at position 1 in DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[(Power[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])/E+x1^2-y1^2-x2^2+y2^2==0&&(x0 y0)/E+x1 y1-x2 y2==0&&x0^2+y0^2+x1^2+y1^2+x2^2+y2^2==1,{x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2}]] is in dimension 6. DiscretizeRegion only supports dimensions 1 through 3.
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Please identify the constants and variables in `rr[t_]`. Do you have a six dimensional space?

Comment: Yes. Everything different from a number is a variable, six of them ranging over the real numbers and one "parameter" t between 0 and 1

Comment: Typo removed, thank you!

Comment: Have you any constraints for `{x0, y0, x1, y1, x2,  y2} ` since in your current definitions `rr, g` we have `NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 50000 integrand evaluations.`

Comment: Yes, constraints are in rr. In particular the variables belong to the unit sphere.

Comment: Do you mean a surface integral or a six-dimensional integral? The latter equals `0`.

Comment: It's an integral over the zero locus of a smooth complex homogeneous polynomial in the unit sphere of $\mathbb C^3$, so a real closed 3-manifold